# GridLines in LogPlot or LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Suppose I have a plot like

```
LogLogPlot[2 x^5/3, {x,0.1,10}, GridLines->Automatic]
```

How can I achieve to get "custom" gridlines to reduce the number of horizontal lines?
I know how to do it with linear scaled plot.

## Edit

For linear scale I do basicly:

```
myGrid[{xmin,xmax,xstep}, {ymin,ymax,ystep}]:=
GridLines->{{#&,/@Range[xmin,xmax,xstep},{#&/@Range[ymin,ymax,ystep])}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `LogLogPlot[2 x^5/3, {x, 0.1, 10}, 
 GridLines -> {{.2, .5, 1, 2, 5}, {.001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000}}]`?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using your linear scaled plot techniques with `LogLogPlot`?

Comment: Maybe you're asking how to customize one set of lines while preserving automatic spacing for the other? As in `LogLogPlot[2 x^5/3, {x, 0.1, 10}, GridLines -> {Range[5], Automatic}]` or the other way around...

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, I know, that I can give the list explicitly. But I search for a way to only give the values in one "decade", which then applies for every decade. Something like `gridlines[{1,2,5},{1,3,7}]`, which sets lines in each decade at these values.

Comment: @Peter How do you do that with linear scale plots?  Can you compare?

Comment: @Peter Are you looking for `GridLines -> {Automatic, Flatten@Table[{1, 2, 5} 10^i, {i, -5, 5}]}` or something similar?

Comment: @Szabolcs something similiar I even tried, but this gives more than three lines in one decade. I would like to have n lines, if the list has length 3.

Answer (score 2):

After some fiddling around I came up with this function:

```
Clear[gitter]
gitter[xspec_, yspec_, logPlot_: False] :=

  Module[{min, max, d, xlines, ylines, i},
   xlines = ylines = None;
   Switch[xspec,
    Automatic, xlines = Automatic,
    {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ},
    {min, max, d} = xspec;
    xlines = Range[min, max, d],
    {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _List},
    {min, max, d} = xspec;
    If[logPlot == False,
     xlines = (Log10[#] &) /@ Flatten[Table[10^i*d, {i, min, max}]],
     xlines = Flatten@Table[10^i d, {i, min, max}]]
    ];
   Switch[yspec,
    Automatic, ylines = Automatic,
    {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ},
    {min, max, d} = yspec;
    ylines = Range[min, max, d],
    {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _List},
    {min, max, d} = yspec;
    If[logPlot == False,
     ylines = (Log10[#] &) /@ Flatten[Table[10^i*d, {i, min, max}]],
     ylines = Flatten@Table[10^i d, {i, min, max}]]];
   {xlines, ylines}];
```

It handles three cases:
(1) Linear scale: The parameters have the form {min, max, step}
(2) logarithmic scale in a normal Plot: The parameters have the form {min, max, istOfValues}
(3) LogPlot or LogLogPlot: as in (2) but the optional Parameter LogPlot has to be set to True.

**Examples:**

```
grid = gitter[{-1, 1, {1, 2, 5, 7}}, {-5, 5, {1, 2, 5, 7}}, True];
lp = LogLogPlot[2 x^5/3, {x, 0.1, 10}, GridLines -> grid, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[10.^i, {i, -5, 5}]}]
```

gives:

[image]

and

```
yticks = Tickmarken[0, 5, {1}, {2, 3, 5, 7}];
gitter = Gitter[{-2, 10, 1}, {0, 5, {1, 2, 3, 5, 7}}];
plot = Plot[Log10[2 E^x], {x, -2, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, yticks}, 
  GridLines -> gitter]
```

gives:
[image]

Tickmarken is a function, I use to make Ticks.

Answer (score 1):

As best I understand, this should do about what you want.  You could of course make the `{1,2,5}` a parameter of the `gridlines` function.

```
gridlines[min_, max_] := 
 Block[{}, 
  Flatten[Outer[Times, {1, 2, 5}, 
    10^Range[Floor[Log10[min]], Ceiling[Log10[max]]]]]]

LogLogPlot[2 x^5/3, {x, 0.1, 10}, GridLines -> {gridlines, gridlines}]
```

[image]