# Why GridLines->function does not work with LogPlot?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

Version 10:

This works:

```
  grids[min_, max_] := Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, Red}, {i, Blue}], 
       {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 1}];
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, GridLines -> grids]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when used with `LogPlot` it gives an error:

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}, GridLines -> grids]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nuts; so I can't even use a custom function! :-S

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  WRI wants to make it really hard not to have nice log spaced gridlines for LogPlot :)

Comment: Related: [(54578)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54578)

Comment: Related: [(4066)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4066/2342)

Comment: I don't mean to boss your question but I find the Accepted answer unsatisfying.  In the past the `GridLines -> {func, func}` form worked; now it does not.  This is still a v10 bug/regression/ugliness and I don't think the matter should be concluded merely because some aspect of that option still works.  One of us could start a new Question about the bi-axis form but I think it better to keep this in one place.  (Thanks to mine we already have two related questions.)

Comment: @Nasser as an author of an answer, please, remove accept. I'm currently filling the issue for Wolfram Support.

Comment: I've reported the issue for Wolfram Support, `[CASE:1212405]`.

Answer (score 2):

For [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html) and [`LogLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html) you need to specify both grids, vertical and horizontal.

```
grids[min_, max_] := 
  Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, Red}, {i, Blue}], {i, Ceiling[min], 
    Floor[max], 1}];
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}, GridLines -> {grids, Automatic}]
```

[image]

And for `{grids, None}`:

[image]

Comment: Interesting observation, but what about grid-lines for the log direction?  `GridLines -> {grids, grids}` does not work.