# Can't get custom x-axis grid lines for a LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, grid-lines

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"]

errorplot1 = 
  ErrorListLogLinearPlot[{{{100.15, -5.3}, 
     ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{150.05, -3.0}, ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{200.32, -2.2},
      ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{250.15, -1.7}, 
     ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{300.18, -1.3}, ErrorBar[0.4]}}];

LogLinearPlot[
  20*Log10[2*Pi*10000*107*10^(-9)*
     x/Sqrt[1 + (2*Pi*x*10000*107*10^(-9))^2]], {x, 80, 350}];

Show[%, errorplot1, AxesStyle -> {Opacity[0], AbsoluteThickness[3]}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {{100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 
    350}, {-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1}}, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

I plotted some measurement data and the theoretical curve of a function. Now I tried making a grid but I can only see the grid of the y-axis. I tried removing the `AxesStyle` (since I made the x-axis invisible) but that didn't work... Here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4066/9490 , but the answers there are much more complicated than what is needed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your x-axis values are on a log scale, so you need to use `Log` values for the gridlines.

```
Show[%, errorplot1, AxesStyle -> {Opacity[0], AbsoluteThickness[3]}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {Log@{100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 
     350}, {-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1}}, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

**Edit** This is if you want to add the gridlines afterwards when combining things with `Show`.  But as OP points out [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105729/9490), you can give the gridline command to the log plot and it will make the conversion automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that and this was really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding the grid lines to the theoretical function. Still curious why it didn't work the way I did it in my question though.

**Edit:** Here's my code that solved it.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

Needs["ErrorBarLogPlots`"]

errorplot1 = 
  ErrorListLogLinearPlot[{{{100.15, -5.3}, 
     ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{150.05, -3.0}, ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{200.32, -2.2},
      ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{250.15, -1.7}, 
     ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{300.18, -1.3}, ErrorBar[0.4]}}];

LogLinearPlot[
  20*Log10[2*Pi*10000*107*10^(-9)*
     x/Sqrt[1 + (2*Pi*x*10000*107*10^(-9))^2]], {x, 80, 350}, 
  GridLines -> {{100, {150, Orange}, 200, 250, 300, 
     350}, {-6, -5, -4, {-3, Orange}, -2, -1}}];

Show[%, errorplot1, AxesStyle -> {Opacity[0], AbsoluteThickness[3]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```